# Pytorch Conv1D gives different size to ConvTranspose1d

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to build a basic/shallow CNN auto-encoder for 1D time series data in pytorch/pytorch-lightning.

Currently, my encoding block is:

```py
class encodingBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
                
        self.conv1d_1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 64, kernel_size=32)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        cnn_out1 = self.conv1d_1(x)
        norm_out1 = self.batchnorm(cnn_out1)
        relu_out1 = self.relu(norm_out1)
        maxpool_out, indices = self.maxpool(relu_out1)
        gap_out = torch.mean(maxpool_out, dim = 2)
        fc_out = self.relu(self.fc(gap_out))
        return fc_out, indices
```

And my decoding block is:

```py
class decodingBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
                
        self.Tconv1d_1 = nn.ConvTranspose1d(64, 1, kernel_size=32, output_padding=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
        self.maxunpool = nn.MaxUnpool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.upsamp = nn.Upsample(size=59, mode='nearest')
        self.fc = nn.Linear(4, 64)

    def forward(self, x, indices):
        fc_out = self.fc(x)
        relu_out = self.relu(fc_out)
        relu_out = relu_out.unsqueeze(dim = 2)
        upsamp_out = self.upsamp(relu_out)
        maxpool_out = self.maxunpool(upsamp_out, indices)
        cnnT_out = self.Tconv1d_1(maxpool_out)
        norm_out = self.batchnorm(cnnT_out)
        relu_out = self.relu(norm_out)            
        return relu_out
```

However, looking at the outputs:

```py
Input size: torch.Size([1, 1, 150])
Conv1D out size: torch.Size([1, 64, 119])
Maxpool out size: torch.Size([1, 64, 59])
Global average pooling out size: torch.Size([1, 64])
Encoder dense out size: torch.Size([1, 4])
...
Decoder input: torch.Size([1, 4])
Decoder dense out size: torch.Size([1, 64])
Unsqueeze out size: torch.Size([1, 64, 1])
Upsample out size: torch.Size([1, 64, 59])
Decoder maxunpool out size: torch.Size([1, 64, 118])
Transpose Conv out size: torch.Size([1, 1, 149])
```

The outputs from the MaxUnpool1d and ConvTranspose1d layers are not the expected dimension.

I have two questions that I was hoping to get some help on:

1. Why are the dimensions wrong?
2. Is there a better way to *"reverse"* the global average pooling than the upsampling procedure I have used?

Answer (score 1):

**1.  Regarding input and output shapes:**
[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch)'s doc has the explicit formula relating input and output sizes.
For [convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html#torch.nn.Conv1d):
[image]

Similarly for [pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool1d.html#torch.nn.MaxPool1d):
[image]

For [transposed convolution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose1d.html#torch.nn.ConvTranspose1d):
[image]

And for [unpooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool1d.html#torch.nn.MaxUnpool1d):
[image]

Make sure your padding and `output_padding` values add up to the proper output shape.

**2. Is there a better way?**
Transposed convolution has its faults, as you already noticed. It also tends to produce ["checkerboard artifacts"](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/).

One solution is to use [`pixelshuffle`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PixelShuffle.html#torch.nn.PixelShuffle): that is, predict for each low-res point twice the number of channels, and then split them into two points with the desired number of features.

Alternatively, you can [`interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate) using a fixed method from the low resolution to the higher one. Apply regular convolutions to the upsampled vectors.
If you choose this path, you might consider using [`ResizeRight`](https://github.com/assafshocher/ResizeRight) instead of pytorch's interpolate - it has better handling of edge cases.